# Custom of placing notes at the Kosel

Tags: sources-mekorot, kotel-western-wall

What is the earliest recorded source mentioning the custom of placing notes at the Kosel?

Answer (score 3):

The Ohr HaChaim Quoted by Rav Palagi, and an even earlier source for this episode with the Ohr HaChaim. [Both are quoted in sefer Hilchisa M'Dorayse](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=58158&st=&pgnum=78) .